# InvalidJsonCasing Error while running the command sfdx:package:publish

Tags: json, salesforcedx

I have created the package with the command **sfdx:package:create -n Consumer -t Unlocked -r force-app** and it updated the **sfdx-project.json** file. Here is my **sfdx-project.json** file -

```
{
    "namespace": "",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "packageDirectories": [{
        "path": "force-app/main",
        "package": "Consumer",
        "versionName": "ver 0.1",
        "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
        "default": true,
        "dependencies": [{
                "package": "AAKonsult Campaign Status"
            },
            {
                "package": "BI WORLDWIDE"
            },
            {
                "package": "Trail Tracker"
            },
            {
                "package": "Lightning DataTable Dev"
            }
        ]
    }],
    "plugins": {},
    "sourceApiVersion": "43.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "Consumer": "0Ho2M000000CaRlSAK",
        "AAKonsult Campaign Status": "04t0V0000019oELQAY",
        "BI WORLDWIDE": "04t1N000000gNiCQAU",
        "Trail Tracker": "04t36000001DzsaAAC",
        "Lightning DataTable Dev": "04t500000006ySIAAY"
    }
}
```

Now when I am running the command **sfdx:package:publish**, I am getting **InvalidJsonCasing** error. Any idea why I am getting this error? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any plugin ? package:publish does not look like salesforce related command ?

Comment: Yes I am using internal plugin which I am mentioning inside plugins section